# Share CIFS mounted drive with all users

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, cifs

A CIFS share, mounted as network drive, seems to be visible only to the user who set it up. Is there a way to make the drive accessible to all the local users on the system ?

Trying to achieve this through command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes-- "map" the drive under each user context. There is no "supported" functionality to do it any other way. Use a logon script to do a `net use` for each user.

"Mapping" the "drive" under the SYSTEM context may be something that gets suggested to you, but the shell treats these "drives" very oddly (often displaying "disconnected" icons for them) and I wouldn't *ever* bank on that method working properly.

Just use a logon script.